# Querying DynamoDB with list contains condition

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Is there any way I can query for any data that has a one of several IDs found in a list?

For example, I have a list with `groupIds`, and I need to query to find all of the posts that fall into any of these `groupIds`. I can't seem to find any sort of 'or' or 'contains' operator except if I use a scan.

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to use the `Scan` operation, DynamoDB is not optimized for these kinds of use cases.